# Why does react-select show a TypeScript warning for assigning to options attribute when using custom types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm getting a warning: `Type 'Participant[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly (Participant | GroupType)[]` for the line where I'm assigning `[p1]` to `options`.

for the following when using react-select where each option is of type `Participant`

```js
const p1: Participant = {
    name: "Bill",
    id: "1"
}

export function MyCustomMultiSelect<
    Participant,
    IsMulti extends boolean = true,
    GroupType extends GroupBase<Participant> = GroupBase<Participant>
    >( props: Props<Participant, IsMulti, GroupType>) {
    return (
        <CreatableSelect options={[p1]} {...props}/>
    );
}
```

My use-case does not involve having groups and I'm following the instructions [here](https://react-select.com/typescript).

Comment: Missing generic constraint: `Participant extends Participant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a type `Participant` defined "somewhere" in your module, which has `name` and `id`.

Your generic `MyCustomMultiSelect` component has a type parameter `Participant`. This can be any type – it is completely generic – but you're using the same name.

Since you're using `p1` directly, it seems that you already know precisely what type you want to pass, so you can remove the generic `Participant` parameter from your component, so `Participant` will just mean `{ name: string, id: string }` (or however you have it defined):

```js
export function MyCustomMultiSelect<
    IsMulti extends boolean = true,
    GroupType extends GroupBase<Participant> = GroupBase<Participant>
    >( props: Props<Participant, IsMulti, GroupType>) {
    return (
        <CreatableSelect options={[p1]} {...props}/>
    );
}
```